# Backbone model.change() not firing

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I'm currently writing an application using Backbone and for some reason, it doesn't update a view, but only in certain circumstances.

If I refresh the page at index.html#/blog/2 it loads the page just fine, everything works great. However, if I refresh the page at index.html#/blog/1 and then change the URL to index.html#/blog/2 and press enter(NOT refresh), the change never gets fired.

This is my router:

```
makeChange: function() {

    // Set activePage to the current page_id => /blog/2
    var attributes = {activePage: this.page_id};
    var $this = this;

    // Loop through all sections in the app
    app.sections.some( function( section ) {

        // Check if section has the page
        if( !section.validate( attributes ) )
        {

            // If it has, set the activePage to /blog/2
            section.set( attributes, {silent: true} );
            // Set active section to whatever section-id was matched
            app.set( {activeSect: section.id}, {silent: true} );

            console.log('Calling change!');

            // Calling change on both the app and the section
            app.change();
            section.change();

            console.log('Change complete!');

            return true;

        }

    });

}
```

This is the app view(which is referenced as "app" up above^):

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function( option ) {

        app.bind( 'change', _.bind( this.changeSect, this ) );

    },

    changeSect: function() {

        var newSect = app.sections.get( app.get('activeSect' ) );
        var newSectView = newSect.view;

        if( !app.hasChanged( 'activeSect' ) )
            newSectView.activate( null, newSect );

        else
        {

            var oldSect = app.sections.get( app.previous( 'activeSect' ) );
            var oldSectView = oldSect.view;

            newSectView.activate( oldSect, newSect );
            oldSectView.deactivate( oldSect, newSect );

        }

    }

});
```

Tell me if you need to see some other classes/models/views.

Comment: Check that the model has actually been updated. Maybe you should bind to the collection instead?

Comment: First is app a model? Just trying to figure out what you are trying to do above. Anyway when navigating the url (without refreshing), are your consoles being called? It should not make a difference if it is a model or collection. You can still bind to the change and reset events.

Comment: @GregRoss @TyroneMichael "app" is an instance of AppView, so it's an extension of Backbone.View. How would I check if the view actually has been updated? I try `console.log( this.page_id )` in router.makeChange() so I know what I'm setting activePage to and it outputs /blog/2 so it **should** have been changed but without any other way of confirming it, I can't be sure. As for the question regarding consoles being called, how can I make sure of that? It does output "Calling change!" as well as "Change complete!" which is output in the router.makeChange() so the router gets called at least..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! This only happens when navigating between different pages(by changing activePage in the section) in the same section, so activeSect in app was never changed, thus never called changeSect(). Now even when activeSect is the same in the app, and activePage has changed in the section, it will call the changeSect() in the app anyway.

In Section-model, I added this:

```
initialize: function() {

    this.pages = new Pages();
    this.bind( 'change', _.bind( this.bindChange, this ) );

},

prepareForceChange: function() {

    this.forceChange = true;

},

bindChange: function() {

    console.log('BINDCHANGE!');
    if( this.forceChange )
    {

        AppView.prototype.forceChange();
        this.forceChange = false;

    }

},
```

In router.makeChange() above this:

```
section.set( attributes, {silent: true} );
app.set( {activeSect: section.id}, {silent: true} );
```

I added:

```
var oldSectId = app.get('activeSect');
if( oldSectId == section.id ) section.prepareForceChange();
```